# gem Faraday Error `undefined method `bytesize' for Hash`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faraday

I want to POST request, using Ruby gem Faraday.
Content-Type is "application/pdf".

my code is below.

```
    client = Faraday.new(endpoint) do |client|
      client.request :retry
      client.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/pdf"
      client.headers['Authorization'] = auth_token
      client.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end

    response = client.public_send(:post, endpoint, params)
```

but, I got Error.

```
undefined method `bytesize' for {:title=>"0722 14 ID:14"}:Hash
```

Please Help me.

Comment: `bytesize` is a method from `String` – it seems that you are passing a hash instead of a string somewhere. Any idea what that `{:title=>"0722 14 ID:14"}` is? Maybe this is supposed to be a JSON payload and you forgot to convert the hash to JSON? (just guessing)

Comment: What is `params`? Please provide a [mcve].